# Sizzle sound coming from speaker when its not used

Tags: sound, speakers

I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 yesterday after 4 years break. Everything is great and i missed Linux so much. But when I am not using my speaker, the sizzle starts. It is **very annoying** and it doesn't happen in Windows. I don't know the model of speakers but its brand is Casper.

I need help, thanks for reading this.

**NEW INFO:** When i go to settings and click on "Sound" sizzle stops. This is one of the most weird things i have seen in Linux. I click on Sound Settings and sizzling stops for 1-2 mins. After it starts, If i click one more time then it stops again.

Answer (score 0):

This used to happen a lot with one of my Lenovo notebooks as well. The issue seems to be coming from a PulseAudio module. Fortunately it's not too difficult to fix. Here's how you can do it:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Edit PulseAudio's `default.pa` file:

   ```
   $ sudo vi /etc/pulse/default.pa
   ```

   ***Note:** You can replace* `vi` *with any other text editor that you prefer. This is more muscle memory than a suggestion that everyone use* `vi`.
2. Search for the line containing `module-suspend-on-idle`. With `vi` it would be:
   • <kbd>?</kbd>
   • Type: `suspend`
   • Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to exit "Find" mode
3. Add a `#` to the start of the line to comment the module out. This will give you something like this:

   ```
   ### Automatically suspend sinks/sources that become idle for too long
   #load-module module-suspend-on-idle
   ```
4. Restart PulseAudio:

   ```
   $ pulseaudio -k
   ```

This should solve the problem, as it has for me any my Lenovo W541.